# vertically align div middle to dynamic height

Tags: html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am currently trying to figure out an way to vertically align an div that is inside an div that has an dynamic height due to it's changing content.

So on this jsFiddle is the setup, 
in the left div you have the content that is inside an wrapper element with an fixed width. Next to that div is another div, this is an wrapper for an image and a div element. And on the right is an element with an position absolute.

The idear is that the text "this is an image" is vertically aligned to the middle of the left div which is dynamic. I would like to do it with CSS but it seems impossible...

You can check out this fiddle to get some more info
http://jsfiddle.net/36sfx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only way to do it is displaying the div as table-cell. I have tried to solve this problem many times before, and I have read before that there are technicals limitation on this issue.

Comment: Isn't there a way using jQuery to figure out the hight of the wrapper div and then with css vertically align the other div to that hight?

Comment: It is possible with **javascript** but it would break layout for many that either dont support javascript or dont want to enable it in sites they dont know. And also would difficult maintainability of a site‘s styling.

Comment: I figured it out using indeed using table cell, some tips on this great site helped me out

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/center-div-with-dynamic-height/
http://jsfiddle.net/36sfx/5/